# PHP editing multi dimensional array with unknown depth

Tags: php, recursion, pass-by-reference

I have an multi dimensional array that can be N levels deep. I would like to manipulate the final array (level 2 in the example below ) we know it's the final array in the recursive function when it finds key 'a'.

I want to add a new key to this array say 'c' and the value of 'c' will be calculated using the value of 'a' and 'b'

I can write a recursive function to loop the array no problem but not sure how to return a new key 'c' and data to the final array.

```
    Array
    (
    [level1] => Array
        (
            [level2_a] => Array
                (
                    [a] => 786578
                    [b] => 34450
                ),

            [level2_b] => Array
                (
                    [a] => 786578
                    [b] => 34450
                )


        )

    )
```

I have tried the following but can't get it return the new data, it simply returns the original array.

```
function calculateAverages(&$arr,$key) {

    if (is_array($arr) ) {       
        if (in_array('a',array_keys($arr))) {
            //add new data to this array    
        }else {
         foreach($arr as $key => $data) {
            calculateAverages($data,$key);
         }
      }
    }
   }
```

Comment: you can use `end()` function in `foreach()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are near to achieve your goal only you have to do changes is to pass reference to foreach loop also. And here there is non requirement of key so I remove it. try this:

```
    $arr =Array
    (
    'level1' => Array
        (
            'level2_a' => Array
                (
                    'a' => 786578,
                    'b' => 34450,
                ),

            'level2_b' => Array
                (
                    'a' => 786578,
                    'b' => 34450,
                )


        )

    );

     function calculateAverages(&$arr) {
       if (is_array($arr) ) {

          if (in_array('a',array_keys($arr))) {
                $avg = ((array_sum($arr))/2);
                $arr['c']=$avg;                     

          }
          else {
             foreach($arr as &$data) {
                calculateAverages($data);                
             }
          }
       }
    }
calculateAverages($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Example: https://eval.in/737280